# Matlab fit() vs. Python numpy

Tags: python, matlab, numpy, surface, data-fitting

I have a matlab script I am converting to Python. Because I want to make a comparison of the programs (not of the individual computation) I want the individual computations to match in both Python and Matlab. The computation regards a polynomial surface fit to some data points.

Matlab:

```
[xData, yData, zData] = prepareSurfaceData( dbMTOM, dbRange, dbOEM )
ft   = fittype( 'poly12' );
opts = fitoptions(ft);
opts.Normalize = 'off';
fitresult = fit([xData, yData], zData, ft, opts)
```

Python:

```
xdegree = 2
ydegree = 3

# Set up the canonical least squares form
Ax = np.vander(x, xdegree)
Ay = np.vander(y, ydegree)
A = np.hstack((Ax, Ay))

# Solve for a least squares estimate
(coeffs, residuals, rank, sing_vals) = np.linalg.lstsq(A, z)
```

The dataset for both codes is equal. The degree of the fit is equal as well(x-degree = 2, y-degree = 3 should be similar to poly12).

I produced none of the above scripts. The matlab script is the original I am trying to convert, the Python script is an adjusted code I found when searching for Python polynomial surface fit.

The resulting coefficients are of the same order of magnitude, but not equal.
The coefficients:

```
[Matlab] p00 = 3703.000000, p10 = 0.470000, p01 = 0.182000, p11 = -0.000021, p02 = 0.000156, p20 = 0.000000
[Python] fx0 = 2632.006003, fx1 = 0.539073, fy1 = -0.579960, --- = 0.000000, fy2 = -0.000182, fx2 = 0.000000
```

I suspect that the fitting methods used here are not the same. However I am unable to find a fitting method that works the same in Matlab and Python. What would be the suggested approach to obtaining equal (or almost equal) results?

Comment: How different are the results? Are these the same coefficients within some small tolerance, or are these truly different polynomials?
How different are the `z` values given by the two polynomials on the same `x,y` data?

Answer (score 0):

The Python version is missing the `p11` term from MATLAB (as shown by your coefficients). From the [MATLAB documentation](http://www.mathworks.com/help/curvefit/list-of-library-models-for-curve-and-surface-fitting.html#btbcvnl)

> Poly12 : Z = p00 + p10*x + p01*y + p20*x^2 + p11*x*y

Additionally your Python version also has two identical columns of 1s (the `x**0` and `y**0` columns). You should ditch one of these because it's redundant.

Therefore to get identical results you need to add a column of "x*y" to your least squares form in Python:

```
# ... Ax and Ay as before
Ay = Ay[:,0:-1] # lose the redundant column of 1s
Axy = (x*y)[:,None] # the indexing makes it an N by 1 array rather than just N
A = np.hstack((Ax, Ay, Axy))

# ... do your least squares as before
```